# Security Trimming on Tree View site navigation

Tags: navigation, security-trimming

Is it possible to add security trimming on the TreeView to only allow the authorized user can see whatever are allowed them to see on the TreeView?

My portal is shared with 3 different users and they can view my library title or document from the TreeView (just view, not access as they have not enough rights to access the library).

**TreeView should not be disabled or hidden for the purpose of document and current location navigation.

Example:
Admin’s View for the TreeView:

->All Site Content

->Library A

->Library B

User1′s view for the TreeView: (No All site Content node & Library B node)

->Library A

User2′s view for the TreeView: (No All site Content node & Library A node)

->Library B

Regards,
Zong

Answer (score 1):

Zong,

You can turn on the publishing feature... and then you will have Navigation in Site Settings!

When you go into Navigation, you can define Audience Targeting on each link, you can manage both Left Navigation and Global Navigation here!

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick reply.

I was think about using the Audience Targeting too, but too bad my SharePoint will giving me error page when I clicking into the User Profile Service.

I try the solution that found online for stop the two "User Profile" service and restart the IIS but the problem error page still there. I also try to create a new application for the User Profile service but unfortunately the luck not on my site.

So due on this issue do you have any suggestion or tips for me?

Thanks and regards,

Zong Low